# Rails 3 Video Converter - make profiles with voyeur HOWTO?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, video-encoding

I'm work with "Rails 3 + CarrierWave + Voyeur" and I need make news profile to convert videos in Voyeur.

I leave here an example :

```
# video_uploader.rb
  version :webmprev do
    process :encode_video => [:webmprev]
    def full_filename(for_file)
      "#{model.id}_#{File.basename(for_file, File.extname(for_file))}.webm"
    end
  end
```

I need to create a separate profile for each video format that I want to create.
I hope that somebody help me.

Thanks.

Andrés.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

**# video_uploader.rb**

```
  version :v1080p do
    process :encode_video => [:mp4_1080p]
    def full_filename(for_file)
      "#{model.id}_#{File.basename(for_file, File.extname(for_file))}.mp4"
    end
  end
```

**# video_converter.rb**

```
modify:
fixed_name = File.basename(current_path, '.*') + "." + format.to_s

by:
fixed_name = File.basename(current_path, '.*') + "." + format.to_s.split("_").
```

```
Create a file-perfil for voyeur in:  
/path_to_ruby/gems/voyeur-0.1.2/lib/Voyeur/video_converters/mp4_1080p.rb
```

**# mp4_1080p.rb**

```
module Voyeur
  class Mp4_1080p < Converter
    def file_extension
      "mp4"
    end

    def convert_options
      "-b 1500k -vcodec libx264 -vpre hq -s hd1080 -g 30"
    end
  end
end
```